# One to one relation in EF Core 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hi everyone and thanks in advance to anyone who will help me;

I'm using .net core 5 with Entity Framework Core and I'm trying to build a webapi for a movie and tv series platform (similar to Netflix so to speak).

I am having a problem with the relationships between my tables; in particular:

I need to create a relationship between the Documentary table and the Actor table;

This is my DocumentaryController.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using microsquare.Services;
using microsquare.Context;
using microsquare.Models;

namespace microsquare.Controllers
{
   [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class DocumentaryController : ControllerBase
   {
       ApiAppContext apiContext;
       public DocumentaryController(ApiAppContext context)
       {
           apiContext = context;
           apiContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
       }
       
       
       [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Documentary>> Get()
       {
           return apiContext.Documentaries.Where(p => p.Rated).ToList();
       }

       [HttpGet("{id}")]
       public ActionResult<string> Get(string id)
       {
           Guid.TryParse(id, out var documentaryId);
           if (documentaryId != Guid.Empty)
           {
               var documentaryFound = apiContext.Documentaries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DocumentaryId == documentaryId);
               if (documentaryFound != null)
               {
                   return Ok(documentaryFound);
               }
               else
               {
                   return NotFound();
               }
           }
           else
           {
               return BadRequest();
           }
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public async Task Post([FromBody] Documentary value)
       {
           apiContext.Documentaries.Add(value);
           await apiContext.SaveChangesAsync();
       }

       [HttpPut("{id}")]
       public void Put(string id, [FromBody] Documentary value)
       {
           Guid.TryParse(id, out var documentaryId);
           if (documentaryId != Guid.Empty)
           {
               var documentaryFound = apiContext.Documentaries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DocumentaryId == documentaryId);

               if (documentaryFound != null)
               {
                   documentaryFound.Title = value.Title;
                   documentaryFound.OriginalTitle = value.OriginalTitle;
                   documentaryFound.GenreCategory = value.GenreCategory;
                   documentaryFound.Cast = value.Cast;
                   documentaryFound.Year = value.Year;
                   documentaryFound.BelongsToCollection = value.BelongsToCollection;
                   documentaryFound.Duration = value.Duration;
                   documentaryFound.Language = value.Language;
                   documentaryFound.OriginalLanguage = value.OriginalLanguage;
                   documentaryFound.SoundTrack = value.SoundTrack;
                   documentaryFound.SoundtrackAuthor = value.SoundtrackAuthor;
                   documentaryFound.MusicAuthor = value.MusicAuthor;
                   documentaryFound.ViewsAndDownloads = value.ViewsAndDownloads;
                   documentaryFound.PosterImage = value.PosterImage;
                   documentaryFound.Rated = value.Rated;
                   documentaryFound.Budget = value.Budget;
                   documentaryFound.Included = value.Included;
                   documentaryFound.Season = value.Season;
                   documentaryFound.Episode = value.Episode;
                   documentaryFound.IsOriginal = value.IsOriginal;
                   documentaryFound.Description = value.Description;
                   documentaryFound.Direction = value.Direction;
                   documentaryFound.ProductionHouse = value.ProductionHouse;
                   documentaryFound.ContentNotice = value.ContentNotice;
                   documentaryFound.ImdbId = value.ImdbId;
                   documentaryFound.Trailer = value.Trailer;
                   documentaryFound.VideoLink = value.VideoLink;
                   documentaryFound.ActorId = value.ActorId;
                   documentaryFound.GenreId = value.GenreId;
                   documentaryFound.ProductionId = value.ProductionId;
                   documentaryFound.VideoId = value.VideoId;
                   documentaryFound.PosterId = value.PosterId;
                   apiContext.SaveChanges();
               }
           }
       }

       [HttpDelete("{id}")]
       public async Task Delete(string id)
       {
           Guid.TryParse(id, out var documentaryId);
           if (documentaryId != Guid.Empty)
           {
               var documentaryFound = apiContext.Documentaries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.DocumentaryId == documentaryId);

               apiContext.Documentaries.Remove(documentaryFound);
               await apiContext.SaveChangesAsync();
           }
       }
           
       }
   }
```

this is my Model Documentary.cs instead:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace microsquare.Models
{

    public class Documentary
    {
        public Guid DocumentaryId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        [Required]
        
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string OriginalTitle { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string GenreCategory { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Cast { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Year { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string BelongsToCollection { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Duration { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string OriginalLanguage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string SoundTrack { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string SoundtrackAuthor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string MusicAuthor { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public BigInteger ViewsAndDownloads { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string PosterImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public bool Rated { get; set; } = false;
        [Required]
        
        public double Budget { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public bool Included { get; set; } = true;
        [Required]
        
        public string Season { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Episode { get; set; }

        public bool IsOriginal { get; set; } = false;
        [Required]
        
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Direction { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string ProductionHouse { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string ContentNotice { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public int ImdbId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string Trailer { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public string VideoLink { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public Guid ActorId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public Guid GenreId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public Guid ProductionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public Guid VideoId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public Guid PosterId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        
        public virtual Actor Actor { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Genre Genre { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Production Production { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
        
        public virtual Poster Poster { get; set; }
    }
    
}
```

this, then, is my ActorController.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using microsquare.Services;
using microsquare.Context;
using microsquare.Models;

namespace microsquare.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ActorController : ControllerBase
    {
        ApiAppContext apiContext;
        public ActorController(ApiAppContext context)
        {
            apiContext = context;
            apiContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        }
        
        
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Actor>> Get()
        {
            return apiContext.Actors.ToList();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public ActionResult<string> Get(string id)
        {
            Guid.TryParse(id, out var actorId);
            if (actorId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var actorFound = apiContext.Actors.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ActorId == actorId);
                if (actorFound != null)
                {
                    return Ok(actorFound);
                }
                else
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task Post([FromBody] Actor value)
        {
            apiContext.Actors.Add(value);
            await apiContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(string id, [FromBody] Actor value)
        {
            Guid.TryParse(id, out var actorId);
            if (actorId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var actorFound = apiContext.Actors.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ActorId == actorId);

                if (actorFound != null)
                {
                    actorFound.Name = value.Name;
                    actorFound.LastName = value.LastName;
                    actorFound.Age = value.Age;
                    actorFound.OriginCountry = value.OriginCountry;
                    actorFound.Picture = value.Picture;
                    apiContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task Delete(string id)
        {
            Guid.TryParse(id, out var actorId);
            if (actorId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                var actorFound = apiContext.Actors.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ActorId == actorId);

                apiContext.Actors.Remove(actorFound);
                await apiContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
            
        }
    }
```

this, finally, is my ApiAppContext.cs file (in which I tried to build the relationships and of which I'll publish only the interested part):

```
builder.Entity<Documentary>().ToTable("Documentary").HasKey(p => p.DocumentaryId);
            List<Documentary> documentaries = new List<Documentary>();
            documentaries.Add(new Documentary() { Title = "Ulisse il Piacere della scoperta – Leonardo da Vinci, genio universale", OriginalTitle = "Ulisse il Piacere della scoperta – Leonardo da Vinci, genio universale", GenreCategory = "Art, Science, History", Cast = "Alberto Angela", Year = "2019", BelongsToCollection = "Ulisse il piacere della scoperta", Duration = "130 min", Language = "Italian", OriginalLanguage = "Italian", SoundTrack = "Ulisse - il piacere della scoperta - The Original Soundtrack", SoundtrackAuthor = "Giuseppe Zambon", MusicAuthor = "Giuseppe Zambon", ViewsAndDownloads = 3610, PosterImage = "https://i.ibb.co/1LbFfK1/1576500282302-leonardo-02.jpg", Budget = 0.00, Season = "20", Episode = "3", Description = "Ulisse - Il piacere della scoperta è un programma televisivo documentaristico ideato da Piero Angela ed Alberto Angela, e condotto da quest'ultimo.", Direction = "Gabriele Cipollitti", ProductionHouse = "Rai", ContentNotice = "Ospiti speciali: Gigi Proietti, Roberto Benigni, Giorgia, Antonio Paolucci, Pinin Brambilla Barcilon", ImdbId = 10, Trailer = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/VPLKt9IiOe8", VideoLink = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/WFj5HpJRQX8", ActorId = actorsInitData[0].ActorId, GenreId = genresInitData[0].GenreId, ProductionId = productionsInitData[0].ProductionId, VideoId = videosInitData[0].VideoId, PosterId = postersInitData[0].PosterId} );

            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasData(documentaries);
            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasOne<Actor>("Actor");
            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasOne<Genre>("Genre");
            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasOne<Production>("Production");
            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasOne<Video>("Video");
            builder.Entity<Documentary>().HasOne<Poster>("Poster");
```

as you can see, I will also have to do other relationships, but since the procedure is the same for all of them, help would be enough for even one of them (I tried with a One to One relationship; isn't that wrong? ). Also, when I try to lounch a petition to my documentary route using Postman, it gives me an OK message but it returns an empty array.

Again I thank anyone who will help me and I apologize for my awful English.

Greetings

Comment: Hi @Alessandro Reina, Do you mean `Get` method in DocumentaryController returns empty array? Did you check the database if it has value in this table ?

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for your answer. that's exactly what I meant (`Get` method in DocumentaryController returns empty array); I've tried many solutions and I'm still trying others but I can't really understand what my mistake is (I've just started to approach .net core and Entity Framework Core).

Comment: Hi @Alessandro Reina, `apiContext.Documentaries.Where(p => p.Rated).ToList();` here is the correct way to get the data. Please check you database if it has value in Documentaries table and check if it has `Rated= true` data in your database.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answers. Thanks to your suggestions I was able to find the solution to my problem. It was returning empty array precisely because, within my database I was filtering only the results that reported the value true to the Rated field but at the same time, within my Model Documentary.cs, I gave the Rated field the default value false (a typical beginner's careless mistake). 
Thanks again for all your answers and for the help you have given me. Now, everything is finally working correctly.

Greetings

Alessandro

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 1):

We will implement a one-to-Zero-or-One relationship between the following Student and StudentAddress entities.

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress Address { get; set; }
}
     
public class StudentAddress 
{
    public int StudentAddressId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

[This Help You](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)